# How can I optimize data transmission in local area network?

Tags: r, sockets, data-transfer

What I want is transport a matrix, e.g. a 1000x1000 matrix (actually biger than that), from NodeA to NodeB in `R`. Now I use the code below:

NodeA:

```
A<-matrix(0,1000,1000)
Conn1<-socketConnection(port=8000, server=TRUE)
write.table(A,file = Conn1, col.names = FALSE)
```

NodeB:

```
HostId<-'x.x.x.x'
Conn2<-socketConnection(host=HostId, port=8000, blocking=TRUE)
A<-read.table(file = Conn2,nrows =1000)
```

But it takes me about 30s to finish data transmission when I run 4 transmissions simultaneously and the dimension of the matrix meets 1.5k (a matrix with ~20Mb). However, in my point of view, the speed of data transmission in FTP is about 10Mb/s, which should much faster than 30s, so I'm wondering how can I improve my code?

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:**

After trying [Ralf Stubner's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49588084/8960845), something strange happened:

`serialize` overrides `write.table` in the test1

```
t1<-proc.time()
S<-unserialize(Con,refhook = NULL)
t2<-proc.time() -t1

t3<-proc.time()
S<-read.table(file=Con)
t4<-proc.time() -t3
```

The output of `proc.time()` is `14s` vs `70s`:

[image: test]

But, when I run 4 pieces of code at the same time in a framework like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48701651/8960845) (test2), `serialize` took much time than `write.table` did.

The output of `serialize` is 101s (the third number in the `ptn`)
[image]

The output of `write.table` is 16s (the third number in the `ptn`)

[image]

Thanks for anyone who could bear such a long post(and my poor English). **The command `serialize` might be the best answer if I have only 1 piece of code to run**, but the strange events in the test2 are really out of my range. I'm wondering if I have to use some external tools such as MPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `read.table` and `write.table` you are converting the table to text before transferring it. This will take time and increase size. Have a look at `serialize()` for converting the matrix to a binary format.

**Edit:** You seem to have trouble with interacting with multiple clients. If you are willing to some learning I would suggest something like ZeroMQ, e.g. via the `rzmq` package. You will have to think about the architecture, though. See http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all for several examples.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it.

Comment: It boosts my test function for about 5 times. But there still have some problem when I run 4 pieces of code at the same time. (it is actually slower than `write.table`). However, thanks for your help!

Comment: @HunterJiang This is odd. ZeroMQ might be an alternative.

Comment: It seems that I should turn to some external tools for help and learn something first. Your effort is really grateful to me, thanks again!